# forzar el tamaño de un arreglo en java con anotaciones?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quiero saber si es posible forzar con anotaciones que el resultado obtenido de un Servicio web que responde en json, con un objeto que trae como propiedad un arreglo de Strings, que la propiedad mencionada no sea nula y que al menos tenga un valor dentro del arreglo y un máximo mediante el uso de anotaciones en JAVA.
Como ejemplo:
Respuesta del Servicio web.
objeto

```
estudiante
{
  nombre:"",
  edad:"",
  aulas:["M1A","C2A"]
}
```

problema:
Evaluar que al crear el objeto "estudiante" de manera local en un dispositivo el atributo "aulas" se encuentre con al menos un elemento y un máximo definible, mediante el uso de anotaciones.

Es posible?

Comment: ¿Java o Android?

Comment: java for android